# Dynamically calling koa router methods in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to dynamically call koa router methods in typescript but am getting a type error.

```
import glob from "glob";
import Router from 'koa-router'
import Application, {BaseContext, Next} from "koa";


export interface Config {
  method: string
  route: string
  handlers: Array<(ctx: BaseContext, next?: Next) => Promise<void>>
}


export default (app: Application) => {
  glob(`${__dirname}/*`, { ignore: "**/index.js" }, (err, matches) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    matches.forEach((mod) => {
      const router = require(`${mod}/router`);

      const routes = router.default;
      const baseUrl = router.baseUrl;
      const instance = new Router({ prefix: baseUrl });

      routes.forEach((config: Config) => {
        const { method = "", route = "", handlers = [] } = config;

        const lastHandler = handlers.pop();

        instance[method.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof Router](route, ...handlers, async function (ctx: BaseContext) {
            return await lastHandler(ctx);
          }
        );

        app.use(instance.routes()).use(instance.allowedMethods());
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Currently I'm getting two type errors. With `instance[method.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof Router]` i've tried keyof and keyof typeof and without keyof and typeof which hasn't worked.

With `return await lastHandler(ctx);` I'm seeing `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` which I'm assuming is because there's no guarantee the index is there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the _second_ error, either handle the case where `handlers` is empty, or ignore the error by casting. What's the full first error?

Comment: @Evert

This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'Object | ((prefix: string) => Router<any, {}>) | { (name: string): Layer; (name: string): boolean; } | Layer[] | { (...middleware: IMiddleware<any, {}>[]): Router<...>; (path: string | ... 1 more ... | string[], ...middleware: IMiddleware<...>[]): Router<...>; } | ... 18 more ... | ((param: string, middleware: IPara...' are callable.
    Type 'Object' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: I appreciate the help!